# What's the correct way to include files in Wordpress TwentyTen theme with it's own jquery scripts and css?

Tags: include, theme-twenty-ten

I want to include a slider in the default Wordpress theme on the home page. I did manage to get the page to show using `<?php if ( is_home() ) { include ('slider.php'); } ?>` but it doesn't look like it's loading the jquery script it needs or the style sheet. I know there's a conflict with scripts and Wordpress, I just don't know how to get it to work.

Sample page is at http://axiomwest.com/

How do you feed in a page with it's own style sheet and scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE!** What I did was just include the slider I was trying to use. I linked the jquery scripts that page needs via the `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` method. I did notice that it takes a couple of seconds to load that portion of the page, but it works. I still think this can be improved, but with time constraints it will have to do. Thanks all for your comments and eagerness to help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the script in a separate file (normally it would be filename.js; I suppose filename.php would work?).

Then, you need to register and enqueue that script file, using `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`

e.g.:

```
function mytheme_register_custom_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/filename.js';
        wp_register_script( 'mytheme_slider', $scriptsrc );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_register_custom_scripts' );

function mytheme_enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme_slider' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_custom_scripts' );
```

Note that registering the script should happen at `after_setup_theme`, but `is_home()` will not be available at this point I don't think, which is why you need to separate the enqueueing function so that it hooks into `wp_head`, by which time `is_home()` is available.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is more appropriate hook than `wp_head` for such, made for that and less likely to get timing wrong.

Comment: For which? The scripts could be *registered* at `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but if he only wants to *enqueue* the script when `is_home()` is true, he'll have to do that at `wp_head`, right?

Comment: @Chip Bennett for either. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is kinda... sub-hook (did I just invent the term?..) of `wp_head`.

Comment: Rarst is right. `wp_enqueue_scripts` runs as part of a function hooked onto `wp_head` at priority 1, so `wp_head` at any priority greater than 0 is too late.

Comment: Okay, updated to change the enqueue to hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` rather than `wp_head`. :)

Comment: Or should I just drop the lot into `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: How can you have a greater priority than 0? 0 is the highest priority, higher values equal later execution..